# Undefined name 'ndimage' even though i have imported it with import scipy.ndimage and loop

Tags: python, undefined, blur

It says undefined name 'ndimage' when i try do the following:

```
import scipy.ndimage
blurred  = ndimage.gaussian_filter(file1, sigma=3)
```

please could someone suggest what is wrong?

also can I put:

```
sigma=1
blurred  = ndimage.gaussian_filter(file1, sigma)
```

i need to somehow create a loop which will show a number of blurred images with varying blurredness.

Thanks in advance for **any** help.

Answer (score 4):

You should use it like the following:

```
import scipy.ndimage
blurred  = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(file1, sigma=3)
```

If you want to use it directly, without writing scipy.ndimage all the time, you can do it as follows:

```
from scipy import ndimage
blurred  = ndimage.gaussian_filter(file1, sigma=3)
```

When you use the "import -module-" statement, everytime you want to access the submodule you need to write it as -module-.-submodule-. When you use "from -module- import -submodule-", you can use -submodule- directly.

Comment: is ndimage a stock picture?